# Interactive pdf. Moving between lines

Tags: cross-referencing, interaction

I made a quiz in LaTex for my exam, and my professor wants me to do the following. When I click on a solution of a problem in the pdf, I would get as a result the problem which is given for that solution, but ONLY that problem, not the rest. I managed to get redirected to the entire page, but thats not what he want's me to do. Here is a part of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[tight,designi]{web}
\usepackage{exerquiz}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstcol}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{moresize}
\definecolor{mojaboja}{rgb}{0.85,0.60,0.90}
\definecolor{BojaZaZadatke}{rgb}{0.50,0.50,0.50}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%------------------------------- komande ---------------------------------------------

\renewcommand\exlabel{Zadatak}
\renewcommand\exlabelsol{}
\renewcommand\exsectitle{Rjesenja za Zadatke}

\renewcommand\sqlabel{\textcolor{blue}{Zadatak}}
\renewcommand\sqslsectitle{\textcolor{blue}{Rjeenja zadataka}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\eq@sqlabel{\textcolor{blue}{Zadatak}}
\renewcommand\eq@sqsllabel{}
\renewcommand\eq@sqslsectitle{Rjeenje zadataka}
\renewcommand\eq@bqlabel{Po\v cetak testa}
\renewcommand\eq@eqlabel{Kraj testa}
\renewcommand\eq@sqslsecrunhead{\textcolor{BojaZaZadatke}{Rjeenja zadataka}}
\makeatother

\title{Prijemni ispiti na Univerzitetu u Tuzli}
\author{Aida Smajloviæ}

\subject{Kreiranje kviza}
\keywords{LaTeX,hyperref,PDF,exercises,quizzes}
\date{\today}

\definecolor{db}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}\newtheoremstyle{mojstil}{}{}{}{}{\color{db}\bfseries}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{mojstil}
\newtheorem{rjesenje}{Rjeenje zadatka}



\begin{document}

\pagecolor{mojaboja}

\maketitle


\section{Prijemni ispit 9.juli 2014 grupa A }

\begin{quiz*}{oQq}
\begin{questions}
\item Sreðivanjem izraza $\frac{\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{1+a}}{\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{1}{1-a}}$ dobijamo
\begin{answers}*{4}
\Ans0  $a$ &
\Ans0  $\frac{1}{1+a}$ &
\Ans1  $-\frac{1}{a}$ &
\Ans0  $\frac{1}{1-a}$
\end{answers}
\begin{solution}  \begin{rjesenje} \normalfont
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{1+a}}{\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{1}{1-a}} &=&\frac{\frac{1+a+1-a}{(1-a)\cdot(1+a)}}{\frac{1-a-1-a}{(1+a)\cdot(1-a)}} \\
&=&\frac{\frac{2}{(1-a)\cdot(1+a)}}{\frac{-2\cdot a}{(1+a)\cdot(1-a)}} \\
&=&\frac{-1}{a}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{rjesenje}
\end{solution}



\item Broj bodova koji su timovi $A,B$\ i \  $C$ osvojili na jednom turniru su u odnosima $A:B=1:2$ i $B:C=3:4$  . Ako je ukupan broj bodova jednak $1700$ , tada broj bodova koji je osvojio tim $A$ je :
\begin{answers}*{4}
\Ans0  $350$ &
\Ans0  $195$&
\Ans0  $200$ &
\Ans1  $300$

\end{answers}
\begin{solution} \begin{rjesenje} \normalfont
\begin{align*}
\underline{\begin{array}{ll}
2\cdot A&=B\\
4\cdot B&=3\cdot C
\end{array}} & \\
\underline{\begin{array}{ll}
A&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot B\\ 
C&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot B
\end{array}} & 
\end{align*}
Dalje je,
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{rrl}
& A+B+C&=1700\\
\Leftrightarrow & \frac{1}{2}B+B+\frac{4}{3}B&=1700\\
\Leftrightarrow & \frac{3B+6B+8B}{6}&=1700 \; \; \Big/ \cdot 6\\
\Leftrightarrow & 17 B&=10200 \; \; \Big/ : 17\\
\Leftrightarrow & B&=600
\end{array}
\end{align*}
Zakljuèujemo, $$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 600 =300.$$
\end{rjesenje}
\end{solution}




\item Za rjeenja $x_{1} \ i \ x_{2}$ kvadratne jednaèine $x^2-2ax + 2a-1=0$  vrijedi relacija $x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2=x_{1}+x_{2}$ , ako je realni parametar $a$ jednak:
\begin{answers}*{4}
\Ans1  $1$ &
\Ans0  $\frac{-1}{2}$&
\Ans0  $0$ &
\Ans0  $-3$
\end{answers}
\begin{solution} \begin{rjesenje} \normalfont
Iz same jednaèine vidimo da je
$$a=1 \ , \ b=-2a \ , \ c=2a-1$$
Prema Vietovim formulama vrijedi:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{lll}
x_{1}+x_{2}&=\frac{-b}{a}&=2a\\
x_{1}\cdot x_{2}&=\;\frac{c}{a}&=2a-1
\end{array}
\end{align*}
Zakljuèujemo,
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{1}+x_{2}&=&2a \ / \ ^2 \\
(x_{1}+x_{2})^2&=&4a^2 \\
x_{1}^2+2x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}^2&=&4a^2 \\
x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2&=&4a^2-2x_{1}x{2} \\
&=&4a^2-2(2a-1) \\
&=&4a^2-4a+2
\end{eqnarray*}
Sada iskoristimo uslov zadataka, tj. $x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2=x_{1}+x_{2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2&=&x_{1}+x_{2} \\
4a^2-4a+2&=&2a \\
4a^2-6a+2&=&0 \ /:2 \ \\
2a^2-3a+1&=&0 \\
a_{1,2}&=&\frac{3\pm \sqrt{9-8}}{4} \\
&=&\frac{3\pm 1}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}
Dakle, dobili smo dva rjeenja $a_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$ \ i \ $a_{2}=1$ pa imamo da vrijednost $a=1$ zadovoljava uslov jednaèine.
\end{rjesenje}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{quiz*}\quad\ScoreField{oQq}

\SolutionsAtEnd

\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the question. It is just a counting enviroment for Solution 1, Solution 2, etc.

Comment: If this is something you are doing as part of an exam, you should not be asking us for help. Are you allowed to have other people do parts of the assessment for you? (I don't see the point in that: who is sitting the exam exactly? Us or you?)